# Use of SLLI for accessing array elements in loop

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, instruction-set

This is the example my teacher gave in C:

```
while (save[i] == k) i+=1;
```

Compiled in RISC-V mode, where `i` is in `x22`, `k` in `x24`, `save` address is in `x25`:

```
slli x10,x22,3                
add  x10,x10,x25   
ld   x9, 0(x10)   
bne  x9,x24, EXIT  
addi x22,x22,1  
beq  x0,x0, Loop  
Exit:.....
```

I don't understand why he used the shift left by immediate (`slli`)

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand why he used the shift left by immediate (`slli`)

Left shifting a number *N* bits produces the same result as multiplying the number by *2<sup>N</sup>*. Since a multiply instruction is generally more expensive (slower) than a shift instruction, left shifting is used instead of a multiply instruction as an optimization when possible: if one of the operands is a constant power of two.

---

`slli` is used to calculate the *offset* into the array `save`. Since `i` corresponds to `x22`, then:

```
slli x10,x22,3
```

multiplies the value of `i` by *8* (i.e., *2<sup>3</sup>*, a power of two) and writes this result to `x10`.

`x25` indicates the base address of the array `save` – the address of its first element – `save[0]`. Together with `x10`, which corresponds to the *offset*, is used to calculate the address of `save[i]`:

```
add  x10,x10,x25
```

At this point, `x10` holds the address of `save[i]`. That element is eventually loaded into `x9`:

```
ld   x9, 0(x10)
```

Comment: @ElenaCiuffreda: normally instead of shifting every iteration, in a loop you'd use `addi x22,x22, 8` to increment a byte-offset by 8.  Or to increment a *pointer* by 8 so you also avoid the `add  x10,x10,x25` address calculation.  If that's real compiler output, your compiler didn't do a very good job; enable a higher optimization level.